# How to update the Owner of a Case/Incident record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm writing a workflow activity that operates against an Incident record.The activity is intended to change the ownerid from a User to a Team that the User is a member of. I have retrieved this Team succesfully. The OwnerId field is the standard Owner type. I have tried the following:

```cs
if (results.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    var er = new EntityReference("team",new Guid(results[0].Attributes["teamid"].ToString()));
    er.Name = results[0].Attributes["name"].ToString();
    updatedEnquiry.OwnerId = er;
    Service.Update(updatedEnquiry);
}
```

results is an EntityCollection
Service is an IOrganizationService

Incident, Team and User entities are out of the box CRM 2011 entities.

After the workflow concludes on the Incident record, the Owner has not changed.

How can I update this Owner field with the new data?

Comment: Clearly, it's because you are reading from resutls where you really wanted results ;)

Comment: Hmmm, let's put that one down to not having Intellisense in the SO editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To update the owner you need to use the `AssignRequest` and is not necessary to specify the `name` attribute for an `EntityReference`

```cs
// incidentId holds the record ID Guid to update

if (results.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    // get the right team
    Entity team = results.Entities[0];

    AssignRequest assignRequest = new AssignRequest
        {
            Assignee = new EntityReference("team", team.Id),
            Target = new EntityReference("incident", incidentId)
        };
    Service.Execute(assignRequest);
}
```

Comment: This is just about identical to what I found out late yesterday, after I'd posted. I was about to post my own answer but you beat me to it. Thanks for your help and +1